# blocking column for edition

Tags: gridview, grid, kendo-ui, blocking

My screen is access control , so I have a prior record in my database (SQL Server) with access times, these times are called steps .

In this screen I'm having problem, there is a form to register the shifts ( days will be allowed to log into the system ) .

In this form I have fields : where do I set a name, a description and a step , after setting I click the add button that will send the data to the grid side .

In this grid I have added the name of the step , day of the week and a button to remove.

My problem is this , my checkbox should be editable , but the name of my step not.

Follows the códiogo of my grid:

```
$("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
columns: [
     { field: "Etapa", title: dialetos.lblEtapa, attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 130, visible: true },
     { field: "Domingo", title: dialetos.lblDomingo, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Domingo ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 85 },
     { field: "Segunda", title: dialetos.lblSegunda, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Segunda ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 80 },
     { field: "Terca", title: dialetos.lblTerca, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Terca ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 75 },
     { field: "Quarta", title: dialetos.lblQuarta, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Quarta ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 80 },
     { field: "Quinta", title: dialetos.lblQuinta, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Quinta ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 80 },
     { field: "Sexta", title: dialetos.lblSexta, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Sexta ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 75 },
     { field: "Sabado", title: dialetos.lblSabado, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Sabado ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 80 },
     { title: "Remover", template: "<span class='k-button' id='btnRemover' onClick='RemoveRowSelecionada()' >Remover</span> ", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 85 }
],
groupable: false,
sortable: true,
editable: true,
filterable: true,
pageable: true,
selectable: "row",
height: 180,
dataSource: vmObjeto.dias,
batch: true,        
change: function (e) {

    },
  }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer that worked for me :

```
$(function () {
  $('#myGrid').on('click', '#chkDomingo', (function () {
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  var grid = $('#myGrid').data().kendoGrid;
  var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
  dataItem.set('Domingo', checked);
}));

$('#myGrid').on('click', '#chkSegunda', (function () {
  var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
  var grid = $('#myGrid').data().kendoGrid;
  var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
  dataItem.set('Segunda', checked);
 }));

$('#myGrid').on('click', '#chkTerca', (function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var grid = $('#myGrid').data().kendoGrid;
var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
dataItem.set('Terca', checked);
}));

$('#myGrid').on('click', '#chkQuarta', (function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var grid = $('#myGrid').data().kendoGrid;
var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
dataItem.set('Quarta', checked);
}));

$('#myGrid').on('click', '#chkQuinta', (function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var grid = $('#myGrid').data().kendoGrid;
var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
dataItem.set('Quinta', checked);
}));

$('#myGrid').on('click', '#chkSexta', (function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var grid = $('#myGrid').data().kendoGrid;
var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
dataItem.set('Sexta', checked);
}));

$('#myGrid').on('click', '#chkSabado', (function () {
var checked = $(this).is(':checked');
var grid = $('#myGrid').data().kendoGrid;
var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(this).closest('tr'));
dataItem.set('Sabado', checked);
}));
});

$("#myGrid").kendoGrid({
columns: [
 { field: "Etapa", title: dialetos.lblEtapa, attributes: { style: "text-align: left" },      width: 130, visible: true },
 { field: "Domingo", title: dialetos.lblDomingo, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Domingo ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 85 },
 { field: "Segunda", title: dialetos.lblSegunda, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Segunda ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 80 },
 { field: "Terca", title: dialetos.lblTerca, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Terca ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 75 },
 { field: "Quarta", title: dialetos.lblQuarta, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Quarta ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 80 },
 { field: "Quinta", title: dialetos.lblQuinta, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Quinta ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 80 },
 { field: "Sexta", title: dialetos.lblSexta, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Sexta ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 75 },
 { field: "Sabado", title: dialetos.lblSabado, template: "<input id='checkbox' #= Sabado ? checked='checked' : '' # type='checkbox' class='checkbox' ' />", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 80 },
 { title: "Remover", template: "<span class='k-button' id='btnRemover' onClick='RemoveRowSelecionada()' >Remover</span> ", attributes: { style: "text-align: left" }, width: 85 }
],
 groupable: false,
 sortable: true,
 editable: true,
 filterable: true,
 pageable: true,
 selectable: "row",
 height: 180,
 dataSource: vmObjeto.dias,
 batch: true,        
 change: function (e) {},
  }).data("kendoGrid");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either [use the schema model for the grid's data source](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/framework/datasource#configuration-schema.model):

```
schema: {
    model: {
        id: "ProductID",
        fields: {
            ProductID: {
                //this field will not be editable (default value is true)
                editable: false
            },
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

or you can set the [field's editor](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-columns.editor) in your grid columns to a non-editable element, e.g. like this (in that case the model column is editable, but the user has no way of editing it manually):

```
{
    field: "Etapa",
    editor: function(container, options) { container.text(options.field) }
    title: dialetos.lblEtapa,
    attributes: {
        style: "text-align: left"
    },
    width: 130,
    visible: true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering me Lars, the two examples solved my problem partially. I can edit but not saved in the database.

How do I block these attempts edition?

Comment: @Isabela I don't understand the problem - what are you trying to do and what is not working? Try explaining in more detail (edit the question). Also add your data source definition.